# How do I send data to the python dictionary according to the fields set in the dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, hashmap, hashtable

I have a dictionary **fields** without values which should take values from **data dict()**

```
data = {'name': 'Robot', 'title': 'This is title'} #missing one required field 'text'

fields = {'name': '', 'title': '', 'text': ''}
```

Now I will send **data** to the **fields dict()**. If the **data** has all the keys as **fields**, **fields dict()** will be populated with the **data values**. Or if the **data** is missing one or more fields it will add 'required' as values to the keys in the **fields dict()**.

according to the above code **fields** should return:

```
fields = {
         'name': 'Robot', 
         'title': 'This is title', 
         'text': 'required'
         }
```

How can I accomplish this in an efficient way? Can anyone please help me through this?

Comment: `{k: data.get(k, 'required') for k in fields}` ?

Comment: That's absolutely working fine. Thank you so much Axe319

Comment: Depending on what you're using it for, it might be more convenient to get the list of missing fields rather than to fill them in; `fields.keys() - data.keys()` will calculate that for you.